# Не заменяется цвет на изображении через Magick.Net

Tags: c#, imagemagick, imagick

В общем, белый цвет заменяется на темно-серый, хотя в TargetColor RGB равен зеленому цвету (R - 0, G - 255, B - 0)

Код:

```
private static MagickImage ChangeWhiteColor(MagickImage Image, Color TargetColor)
    {
        Image.Opaque(MagickColor.FromRgb(255, 255, 255), 
            MagickColor.FromRgb(TargetColor.R,
            TargetColor.G,
            TargetColor.B));
        return Image;
    }
```

В чем проблема?